# UPDATE Query to store running count in a field every month

Tags: ms-access

Ok so I'm working on a MS Access database and I have hit a roadblock and hoping you guys can help me out. Following is the background of my database:

My company does monthly reports on Employee performance based on how many 'cases' each worker has missed the deadline on. So I have 2 tables, table 1 has employee info in 3 fields: Unit, Worker Code and Name. Table 2 has fields: Unit, Worker Code, Case number (list of all cases that are not finished in time).

What I need is to generate a report which shows me a count of cases not done in time and I need the report to show numbers for last 3 months. I was thinking if I could use a UPDATE query to overwrite the count each month in a table. My resulting table will have the fields : Unit, Worker Code, count of current month cases, count of prior month cases and count of 2 month prior cases. I'm attaching a screenshot of the report that we create in excel and manually update each month.

Please guide me how would I be able to achieve that sort of report in access without manually inputting numbers each month.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyeYi.png)

Comment: @hansup I'm not sure I exactly understand what you are asking but if you mean if I'm allowed to store or have authorization then the answer is yes.

Comment: No. Every month we get new data. The new data is for current month only. There is no history data. So basically when I perform the count of cases, I want to store the count in a table. When I store the count this month, last month's count should be stored in the last month field. What I'm thinking is have a table with 3 fields, current, last, prior. When I run the count for this month, it overwrites the data in current field while data from current field is copied to last and from last to prior. And UPDATE doesn't not work with calculated fields. Hope that explains

Comment: I think I understand now.  Thanks.  I wouldn't attempt that as an `UPDATE` query.  I think a VBA procedure would be easier.

Comment: Would you or someone will be able to guide me on that please? I'm very raw in VBA coding department. Thank you

Comment: It may not be practical for you then.  Are you so raw that you don't know how to use a `DAO.Recordset` in VBA code?

Comment: Correct. VBA code I'm limited to docmd.openquery and docmd.openreport or application.Quit

Comment: Rats!  Sounds like guidance would have to include teaching you VBA basics.  That is beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow question.  Let's see whether someone else is able to offer you an appropriate solution.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Appreciate it. I used to code in visual basic about 18 years ago but never kept up with it. So if someone is willing to guide it won't be as gruesome as guiding someone with no knowledge